# Install programs from the SCCM via a script

Tags: powershell, windows-10, sccm

I would like to be able to install/uninstall programs on my pc via the SCCM using a script file.

I would like to run the script and have it install the specified program on the pc that it is running on.

https://timmyit.com/2016/08/08/sccm-and-powershell-force-installuninstall-of-available-software-in-software-center-through-cimwmi-on-a-remote-client/

I have tried the script above but just cannot get it to work i believe this is because it is designed to install the program on a remote machine and i have not bee able to figure out if it is possible to do this on a local machine that only has access to the SCCM for a USER perspective not an admin perspective.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated as i cant see that there are any command line arguments to perform and install by using the SCCM.

Comment: It is almost impossible to be of any help without knowing more details. Actually you don't need a script to install programs with SCCM. You could take a look at [PSAppDeployToolkit](https://psappdeploytoolkit.com/) what's a kind of made for it and what should make it easier even without that much scripting knowledge.

Comment: @Olaf the problem I have is that I'm a very locked down user and can only install programs and applications via the SCCM and I am always in a different computer each time so I would like to create a script that I can simply double click and it would install all the programs that i want to install from the SCCM is that something that PSAppDeployToolkit would allow me to do?

Comment: That actually does not make that much sense ... how can you create SCCM packages or applications without being an administrator?

Comment: @Olaf I never stated that I wanted to create packages or applications just that I wanted to install them from the SCCM as all the apps I need are already available to be installed in SCCM I just want to create a program that will install them for me

Comment: So I did not get what's the question. If you already have SCCM packages available you can make them mandatory and they're installed automatically. Your question might be asked in the wrong forum here.  ;-)

Comment: @Olaf I can't do that tho as I am a standard user and not a system administrator

Comment: So you have to use the way your administrator designed for you ... most likely the Software Center. Just mark them all and click install all marked ...

Comment: @Olaf but I would like to create a script that automatically installs all the programs I want by simply double clicking there must be a way to do it right?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this because as Olaf tried to explain, sccm already has a way for automatic installation. Your system seems to be specifically set up for manual installation and no sccm admin that wants automatic installation should set it up that way, that's kinda the point of the setup here. It might still be doable through a lot of wmi scripting but as there is no real point to it I never saw anyone giving a real howto for it. Your approach should definitely be to talk to your sccm admin about it, he can solve your problems (and he definitely should)

Comment: Ah okay thats kinda annoying thank u anyway

Comment: Ah okay thats kinda annoying thank u anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly after doing research this is only possible on the admin side of the SCCM and cannot be done on the client side however it would be cool if it was possible